# Updating Azure App Service web.config to load .ttf font files

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-config

Wracking my brain but can't seem to find the solution. I have a .ttf font file, located on Azure storage blob, being used for a custom font on my Azure App Service site. I get a 404 "resource not found" error for this file.

After reading a ton of documentation on this, it seems I need to add a couple of lines of code, for a new "mimetype", to the web.config file. Older versions of Azure had this in "Extensions" or "Application Settings".

Other people show the ability to do so in Kudu under the "Debug" option. However, I can't seem to find either of those - "Configuration" shows environment variables and I don't see a "Debub" option in my Kudu portal.
[Kudu Console without "Debug" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ay42.png)

How do I actually update the web.config file or at the very least be able to load a .ttf file???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Kudu, then go to wwwroot folder and edit web.config file with the following, or just create one in case it's not there:

[image: kudu image]

PS: previous image shows LogFiles folder, but it should be wwwwroot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, it looks like you're first choosing CMD or PowerShell from the "Debug console" dropdown and this isn't showing up for me. I see "SSH" or "Bash".

Comment: I see, your app service is linux. try creating/editing the web.config using bash

Comment: Awesome. That worked (after searching how to create a file in Bash :) ). Appreciate the help!